# How can I deserialize both responses using the same class?

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.5

I am currently getting data from an API that comes out like this:

```
{
    "messages": [
        ...somedata...
    ],
    "timestamp": 123456,
    "request": 1
}
```

Which I can easily deserialize into:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("messages")]
    public List<...> Messages { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("request")]
    public int RequestsLeft { get; set; }
}
```

However that same API can also some times return the data with a short name on the properties like this:

```
{
    "m": [
        ...somedata...
    ],
    "t": 123456,
    "r": 1
}
```

How can I use the same class(what needs to be changed) to deserialize both format or is that not possible and I need a class for each of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public class Data
{
  [JsonProperty("messages")]
  public List<...> Messages { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("m")]
  public List<...> m_list { 
    get{ return Messages; }
    set{ Messages = value; }
  }

  [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
  public int Timestamp { get; set; }

  ... 

  [JsonProperty("request")]
  public int RequestsLeft { get; set; }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class Data
{
    private string[] messages;

    [DataMember(Name = "messages")]
    public string[] Messages
    {
        get
        {
            return messages;
        }

        set
        {
            messages = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "m")]
    public string[] AlternativeMessages
    {
        get
        {
            return messages;
        }

        set
        {
            messages = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "timestamp")]
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "request")]
    public int Request { get; set; }
}

public class JsonUtils
{
    public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        return obj;
    }
}




var value = "{ \"m\": [\"Hi!\", \"Prix\"], \"timestamp\": 123456, \"request\": 1 }";

var data = JsonHandler.JsonDeserialize<Data>(value);
```